# Core Data Fault objects

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am using Core Data in my project.

I have faced a problem, when fault object's relations do not unfault after i access them in code.

My question: is it possible, that fault relation can stay fault after accessing to it.

upd:

```
NSManagedObjectContext *context = self.context;
    
if (!context)
return nil;
    
    NSFetchRequest *request = NSFetchRequest.new;
request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:name inManagedObjectContext:context]; 
    request.predicate = predicate;
    
    if (sortDescriptors)
        [request setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];
        
    return [context executeFetchRequest:request error:nil];
```

context - is default context on main thread. I access object's relationships on main thread.

Comment: what about showing some code?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what the problem is/what you want to achieve. If your fetch request returns faults instead of objects, do

```
request.returnsObjectsAsFaults = NO;
```

If you also want some properties/relationships of your fetched objects to be fetched as well/not be faults, do

```
[request setRelationshipKeyPathsForPrefetching:@[@"someProperty1",@"someOtherPropertyInEntity"]];
```

This last one sometimes helps tremendously when improving performance.